# Select выбираем один из вариантов где value 0, значит скрываем все поле tr, как сделать?

Tags: javascript, css

**Всем привет.**
Есть форма, она на table, в ней есть строки, в каждой строке есть свой селект и импут поля.

В селекте есть 2 варианта,  value 1 и value 0, как при выборе варианта с value 0, делать прозрачным всю tr строку ? ну или при выборе варианта не по валуе, а по названию, у валуе 1, (Показывать), у валуе 0 (Не показывать).

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.addrazmer', function() {

    let obj = `
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:center">
            <select style="width:135px; height: 30px" name="" id="show_tov">
              <option value="1">Показывать</option>
              <option value="0">Не показывать</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="texttttaf" name="" />
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="texttttaf" style="width:70px; color: #FF2525;" name="" /> руб
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center">
           <a title="Удалить" class="btnd itemdel">Удалить</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
  `;
    const newRow = $(obj);

    $('.addlist').append(newRow);
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table th {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #efefef;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.table td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.btnp,
.btnd {
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btnp {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
  background: #0078B9;
}

.btnd {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 8px 0 8px;
  background: #FF2525;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width:550px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Размер</th>
      <th width="120">Цена</th>
      <th width="90"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="addlist">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <select style="width:135px; height: 30px" name="" id="show_tov">
          <option value="1">Показывать</option>
          <option value="0">Не показывать</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="texttttaf" value="" name="" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="texttttaf" style="width:70px; color: #FF2525;" value="" name="" /> руб
      </td>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <span class="btnd">Удалить</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<a title="Добавить размер" class="btnp addrazmer">Добавить размер</a>
```

Comment: Обратите внимание, что при создании нового элемента, вы добавляете select с одним и тем же id="show_tov", но id на странице всегда должен быть уникальный.

Comment: Да это в примере, а так там все по феншуй идет, уникальное.